# How to populate a textbox from database when i select an item from combo box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

**How can i populate a textbox my database column 2 when i select an item from combobox which is the ComboBox is populated with database column 1**

This is what i want to happen:
When i select an item from the combobox the textbox will automatically be filled with data.

[This is what i want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY0wX.png)

This my Table:
What i want is when i select client name the textbox will automatically be filled by the clients contact person.

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7kkI.png)

**This is what i tried **

```
 Private Sub clientNameText_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clientNameText.SelectedIndexChanged, clientNameText.TextChanged
    Try

        connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Nikko Jaze Fabellon\Documents\ASRASIM.accdb")
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
        Dim cmdText = "select [Contact Person] from ServiceRecords where [ClientName] =' " & clientNameText.Text & "'"
        dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdText, connection)
        Dim dtable As New DataTable
        dataAdapter.Fill(dtable)

        reader = dataAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            cPersonText.Text = reader.GetInt32("Contact Person")
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  You are likely to get more down votes than answers if you show no effort and are basically asking someone to write your code for you

Comment: sorry i updated it, i tried a few but nothing happens. im a newbie in vb.net

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [TOUR].  There isnt an actual question but mainly, "it failed" is a very poor problem description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bind the `TextBox` to the same data source, e.g.

```
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables("Clients"), "ColumnName")
```

EDIT: This time, please actually do what I suggest.  You need your query to retrieve all the columns you want to display.  You `Fill` a `DataTable` using a data adapter and then bind that `DataTable` to your controls.  That's it, that's all.  E.g.

```
Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Name, Description FROM MyTable", "connection string here")
Dim table As New DataTable

adapter.Fill(table)

With myComboBox
    .ValueMember = "ID"
    .DisplayMember = "Name"
    .DataSource = table
End With

myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myDataTable, "Description")
```

That's you need.  Make the selection in the `ComboBox` and the `TextBox` will display the correct data.

Comment: If you bind the same `DataTable` to a `ComboBox` and a `TextBox` then selecting a record in the `ComboBox` will display the field value from the same record in the `TextBox`. That's a fact. If it didn;t work for you then you did it wrong.  For one thing, you'd need to have retrieved the column that you bind to the `TextBox` with the query that populated the `DataTable`. Your original code indicates that you retrieved only one column, but you'd need at least two to populate two different controls.

Comment: i updated my codes please see above. im not getting an error but still i cant populate the textbox after i select an item from comboBox. Is this part where im wrong? cPersonText.Text = reader.GetInt32("Contact Person")

Comment: Yes, that part is wrong. The whole point of data-binding is that it moves the data for you rather than you having to do it yourself.  You DO NOT call `ExecuteReader` at all. You call `Fill` to populate a `DataTable` and then you bind that `DataTable` to your `ComboBox` and your `TextBox`. Instead of adding the latter, you have removed the former. If you had just done what I said then it would be working but you pretty much ignored everything. You didn;t change your query, you didn't bind the `TextBox` and you unbound the `ComboBox`. I'll add a more extensive example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much  (jmcilhinney) now i understand, im sorry for not understanding ur previous answer because im in a rush now becuase defense is coming 8 days from now, im fixing every problem that is occuring in my program and still i have to make a printing fucntion. THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR!!! i will remember ur advise!!!